# Why are humans considered a delicacy in the Land of Ooo?

Tags: plot-explanation, adventure-time

During the episode where Jake meets Lady Rainicorn's parents.  Misinformation happens and he accidently gives her parents permission to eat Finn.  They then attack him in a blind hunger-rage and explain that humans are now extinct and are a delicacy to them.

The question is **why**?  Were they considered that before the mass extinction or because of it?  And is it only Rainicorns that like to eat humans, or do other species of Ooo desire the taste of human flesh?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that back before the Rainicorn/Dog war, humans wouldn't venture into Rainicorn territory often, because most humans have an animal companion. This companion is usually a dog. Maybe the Rainicorns were low on resources, and the occasional human would be wonderful to them. After the war, humans were extremely scarce around their territory. Like truffles, which are also extremely rare, they were considered a delicacy to the rainicorns.